# Abstract algebra- Center subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $a$ belongs to a group and $|a|=5$. Prove that $C(a)=C(a^2)$. Find an element $a$ from some group such that $|a|=4$ and $C(a)$ does not equal $C(a^2)$.

Comment: What have you tried? MSE, although a math website, wants to look at what work you have attempted. (Known as context) If you share a good question like this, give context, and use good formatting, your question will be well recieved...

Comment: Hints: $\langle a\rangle=\langle a^2\rangle$; consider the dihedral group of order 8.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: $C(a) \subseteq C(a^n)$ for any $a \in G$ and $n \in \Bbb N$.

Proof: Suppose $x \in C(a)$, i.e. $ax=xa$. Then, $a^nx = a\cdots aax = a \cdots axa = a \cdots xaa = \cdots = xa^n$, so $x \in C(a^n)$.

So now the answer to your question is that $C(a) \subseteq C(a^2) \subseteq C((a^2)^3)$, but $(a^2)^3 = a^6 = a^1 = a$, so $C(a) \subseteq C(a^2) \subseteq C(a)$, so $C(a) = C(a^2)$.